# How do you count frequency of element in a vector using count_if function?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

My code

```
bool func(int i){
    if(i==x)return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int findFrequency(vector<int> v, int x){
    
    int ans=count_if(v.begin(),v.end(),func);
    return ans;
}
```

How do I pass 'x' in the count_if function?
Here, 'x' is the number present in the vector which is to be counted.

Comment: Why not use `count` instead of `count_if`?

Comment: @Arpan You should research "functionoids" and then "lambdas"

Comment: Functionoids?.. 0_o

Comment: @bipll [What the heck is a functionoid, and why would I use one?](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/functionoids.html)

Comment: More commonly known as "functors".

Answer (score 3):

To count a specific value in the vector, you can use `std::count()`:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v;
int x = 1;
auto c = std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
```

If you want to use `std::count_if()`, you can use a function object with state:

```cpp
struct if_counter {
    int x;
    bool operator()(int y) { return x == y; }
};

auto x = 1;
auto c = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), if_counter{x});
```

Basically, this is the same as you get from using a lambda expression:

```cpp
int x = 1;
c = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [x](int y){ return x == y; });
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/W614YY)

Answer (score 1):

Using a lambda function inside your `findFrequency` function is a nice clean approach. The above answer @idclev notes this, here's a version that's more similar to your existing code:

```
int findFrequency(std::vector<int>& v, int x) {

    auto func = [&] (int i) {       // [&] means 'capture by reference'
        if (i == x) return 1;
        else return 0;
    };

    int res = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), func);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: In this case, capture by reference vs capture by value, the overhead to create the lambda is about the same. So I would capture `x` by value instead, so there is 1 less memory dereference performed inside the lambda body per loop iteration.